# How to get a splitted string last element in windows batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this `windows batch` file to make easier my frontend developers work:

```
@echo off
echo.

set NEW_COMPONENT=%1
set NEW_COMPONENT=%NEW_COMPONENT:/=\%
set NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT=%NEW_COMPONENT:/= %

REM get the component name (last item form '/' spearated array)
for %%a in ("%NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT%") do set "COMPONENT_NAME=%%~nxa"

set HTML=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\%COMPONENT_NAME%.html
set SCSS=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\_%COMPONENT_NAME%.scss
set JS=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\_%COMPONENT_NAME%.js
set IMG=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\img

mkdir src\%NEW_COMPONENT%
echo | set /p x=created folder: src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\

echo. 2>%HTML%
echo | set /p x=created file: %HTML%

echo. 2>%SCSS%
echo | set /p x=created file: %SCSS%

echo. 2>%JS%
echo created file: %JS%

mkdir %IMG%
echo | set /p x=created folder: %IMG%\

echo.
```

Now they ask me put `import %COMPONENT_NAME% from '%PARENT_COMPONENT';` string into first line of parent component `.js` files to link automatically the new component and the parent.

The user can use this like this:

```
create-component.bat components/header/nav
```

In this case the `%COMPONENT_NAME%` will be `nav` but how can I catch the item before last item? In this case it will be `header`

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` can work with relative paths. So `components\header\nav\..` is the same as `components\header`. From that path you need the last element `%%~nxA`:

```
set "NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT=components\header\nav"
for %%A in ("%NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT%\..") do set "COMPONENT_NAME=%%~nxA"
echo %COMPONENT_NAME"
```

Comment: I need the element before the last element. Not the last one.

Comment: output is `header`. I guess that's what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `for` loop section to this (ammended first loop and added line):

```
for %%a in ("%NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT%") do set "COMPONENT_TMP=%%~pa"
for %%i in ("%COMPONENT_TMP:~0,-1%") do set "COMPONENT_NAME=%%~nxi"
```

So, your ammended script:

```
@echo off
echo.

set NEW_COMPONENT=%1
set NEW_COMPONENT=%NEW_COMPONENT:/=\%
set NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT=%NEW_COMPONENT:/= %

REM get the component name (last item form '/' spearated array)
for %%a in ("%NEW_COMPONENT_TO_SPLIT%") do set "COMPONENT_TMP=%%~pa"
for %%i in ("%COMPONENT_TMP:~0,-1%") do set "COMPONENT_NAME=%%~nxi"

set HTML=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\%COMPONENT_NAME%.html
set SCSS=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\_%COMPONENT_NAME%.scss
set JS=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\_%COMPONENT_NAME%.js
set IMG=src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\img

mkdir src\%NEW_COMPONENT%
echo | set /p x=created folder: src\%NEW_COMPONENT%\

echo. 2>%HTML%
echo | set /p x=created file: %HTML%

echo. 2>%SCSS%
echo | set /p x=created file: %SCSS%

echo. 2>%JS%
echo created file: %JS%

mkdir %IMG%
echo | set /p x=created folder: %IMG%\

echo.
```